# Unity. Исключение [дубликаты BuildConfig.class] при сборке Gradle

Tags: android, unity3d

Использую Unity 2023.1.9

При сборке на андроид возникает исключение, которое я не могу длительное время решить:

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
ERROR:C:\Projects\NewProject\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\build\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\release\classes.jar: R8: Type com.NewProject.NewProject.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: C:\Projects\NewProject\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\build\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\release\classes.jar:com/NewProject/NewProject/BuildConfig.class, C:\Projects\NewProject\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\launcher\build\intermediates\javac\release\classes\com\NewProject\NewProject\BuildConfig.class

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Насколько я понял, два раза генерируется BuildConfig.class в двух разных местах. Почему так происходит?

Comment: Очень похоже что у вас именно эта проблема: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67131132/5479247